# processing map structure using spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file which contains map structure which needs to be processed.I have used below code.I got the intermediate result as RDD[ROW].Data shown below.

```
val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("student-example").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val studentdataframe = sqlcontext.read.parquet("C:\\student_marks.parquet")
    studentdataframe.take(4).foreach(println)
```

Data looks like this.

```
  [("Name=aaa","sub=math",Map("weekly" -> Array(25,24,23),"quaterly" -> Array(25,20,19),"annual" -> Array(90,95,97)),"2018-02-03")],
  [("Name=bbb","sub=science",Map("weekly" -> Array(25,24,23),"quaterly" -> Array(25,20,19)),"2018-02-03")],
  [("Name=ccc","sub=math",Map("weekly" -> Array(20,21,18),"quaterly" -> Array(25,16,25)),"2018-02-03")],
  [("Name=ddd","sub=math",Map("weekly" -> Array(25,24,23),"quaterly" -> Array(21,19,15),"annual" -> Array(91,86,64)),"2018-02-03")]
```

Data is in RDD[ROW] format.Here I want the sum of only annual marks.I want to skip the record if annual marks are not there.I want output like this.

```
Name=aaa|sub=math|282
Name=ddd|sub=math|241
```

Please help me.

Comment: can you share the schema of studentdataframe?

Comment: hi Ramesh,please find the schema.root
 |-- neid: string (nullable = true)
 |-- counters: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: long (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- fdn: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)

Comment: Is there any way that we can create RDD from this Dataframe and proceed.

Comment: I am not understanding how marks is coming in `marks(25,24,23)` so can you tell whats the output of studentdataframe.show(4)? you can update the question with schema and show(4)

Comment: Hi Rameh,I can't show the actual data.I simply changed the field names which can be applied to student.so there may a miss match in schema  and data.can you proceed with assuming above data as a RDD[Row]

Comment: Your RDD[Row] seems to be taken from pyspark. I need to test before I suggest you solution. Do one thing then. just do . studentdataframe.show(1) and change the data inside to equivalent something else and update the question

Comment: Actual data is having many fields .if I do  studentdataframe.show(1) on actual data I am getting many fields  headers.If I convert that to student data again there may be a miss match.so what I would like is will proceed with RDD[Row].please help to get  solution from RDD[Row].

Comment: ok then just update the question with how would you proceed to create a dataframe from the RDD[Row] given in question using scala.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166148/discussion-between-khumar-and-ramesh-maharjan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by using a `udf` function and you don't even need to convert into `rdd` .

I used your given sample data as a way to form test `dataframe` as

```
val studentdataframe = Seq(
  ("Name=aaa","sub=math",Map("weekly" -> Array(25,24,23),"quaterly" -> Array(25,20,19),"annual" -> Array(90,95,97)),"2018-02-03"),
  ("Name=bbb","sub=science",Map("weekly" -> Array(25,24,23),"quaterly" -> Array(25,20,19)),"2018-02-03"),
  ("Name=ccc","sub=math",Map("weekly" -> Array(20,21,18),"quaterly" -> Array(25,16,25)),"2018-02-03"),
  ("Name=ddd","sub=math",Map("weekly" -> Array(25,24,23),"quaterly" -> Array(21,19,15),"annual" -> Array(91,86,64)),"2018-02-03")
).toDF("name", "sub", "marks", "date")
```

which gave me

```
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|name    |sub        |marks                                                                                                            |date      |
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
|Name=aaa|sub=math   |Map(weekly -> WrappedArray(25, 24, 23), quaterly -> WrappedArray(25, 20, 19), annual -> WrappedArray(90, 95, 97))|2018-02-03|
|Name=bbb|sub=science|Map(weekly -> WrappedArray(25, 24, 23), quaterly -> WrappedArray(25, 20, 19))                                    |2018-02-03|
|Name=ccc|sub=math   |Map(weekly -> WrappedArray(20, 21, 18), quaterly -> WrappedArray(25, 16, 25))                                    |2018-02-03|
|Name=ddd|sub=math   |Map(weekly -> WrappedArray(25, 24, 23), quaterly -> WrappedArray(21, 19, 15), annual -> WrappedArray(91, 86, 64))|2018-02-03|
+--------+-----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

As I said a simple `udf` function should solve your requirement so the `udf` function can be as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def sumAnnual = udf((annual: Map[String, collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Int]]) => if (annual.keySet.contains("annual")) annual("annual").sum else 0)
```

and you can use it as below

```
studentdataframe.select(col("name"), col("sub"), sumAnnual(col("marks")).as("sum")).filter(col("sum") =!= 0).show(false)
```

which will give your required `dataframe` as

```
+--------+--------+---+
|name    |sub     |sum|
+--------+--------+---+
|Name=aaa|sub=math|282|
|Name=ddd|sub=math|241|
+--------+--------+---+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Hi, I tried to save the output in a CSV format using below code line datadf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("C:\\myfile.csv") but it is  giving an error saying :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support map<string,bigint> data type..How can save the file

Comment: csv format saving doesn't support Map and Array. You will have to convert them to string to save them to csv file. Or better option would to save them as jsons. Even better option is parquett format

Comment: I want to save it in  csv format.So that it same file is given as a input to other aplication.How can I convert  it string. and save it in CSV.

Comment: there is a inbuilt function `to_json` you may use that to convert your map to string. :)

Comment: I have tried like this val df3=studentdataframe.toJSON.toString().After this when I tried to do saveAsText or write to csv  ,it is giving error as "not a member of string"

Comment: please guide me if i am doing wrong ,to save the result in csv or textfile.thanks

Comment: I was talking about [to_json](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#to_json-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-)

Comment: You are doing a mistake while saving in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49092979/write-dataframe-result-to-csv-facing-issue-with-map-data-type . I have answered pointing out your mistake :)