# Write dataframe to csv with datatype map<string,bigint> in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I have a file which is file1snappy.parquet. It is having a complex data structure like a map, array inside that.After processing that I got final result.while writing that results to csv I am getting some error saying

```
"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support map<string,bigint> data type."
```

Code which I have used:

```
val conf=new SparkConf().setAppName("student-example").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlcontext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    val datadf = sqlcontext.read.parquet("C:\\file1.snappy.parquet")
    def sumaggr=udf((aggr: Map[String, collection.mutable.WrappedArray[Long]]) => if (aggr.keySet.contains("aggr")) aggr("aggr").sum else 0)
datadf.select(col("neid"),sumaggr(col("marks")).as("sum")).filter(col("sum") =!= 0).show(false)
    datadf.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("C:\\myfile.csv")
```

I tried converting datadf.toString() but still I am facing same issue.
How can write that result to CSV.

spark version 2.1.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spark `CSV` source supports only atomic types. You cannot store any columns that are non-atomic

I think best is to create a JSON for the column that has `map<string,bigint>` as a datatype and save it in csv as below.

```
import spark.implicits._ 
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

datadf.withColumn("column_name_with_map_type", to_json(struct($"column_name_with_map_type"))).write.csv("outputpath")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: it is saying $ is not a member of String Context

Comment: `import spark.implicits._`   `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ `import these two

Comment: while importing  spark.implicits._ it is saying object not found spark

Comment: val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

Comment: If you are using spark2.0+ you should use `SparkSession` as an entry point rather than the `SparkContext`

Comment: in maven i have added all the dependencies like spark-core,scala,spark-sql,databricks csv.but still i am unable to create val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()  and importing spark.implicits._

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166184/discussion-between-shankar-koirala-and-khumar).

Answer (score 1):

**You are trying to save the output of**

```
val datadf = sqlcontext.read.parquet("C:\\file1.snappy.parquet")
```

**which I guess is a mistake as the udf function and all the aggregation done would go in vain if you do so**

So I think you want to save the output of

```
datadf.select(col("neid"),sumaggr(col("marks")).as("sum")).filter(col("sum") =!= 0).show(false)
```

So you need to save it in a *new dataframe variable* and use that variable to save.

```
val finalDF = datadf.select(col("neid"),sumaggr(col("marks")).as("sum")).filter(col("sum") =!= 0)
finalDF.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save("C:\\myfile.csv")
```

And you should be fine.